# Looping over python dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary like below

```
    car_dict=
{
'benz': {'usa':876456, 'uk':965471},
'audi' : {'usa':523487, 'uk':456879},
'bmw': {'usa':754235, 'uk':543298}
}
```

I need the output like below

```
benz,876456,965471
audi,523487,456879
bmw,754235,543298
```

and also in sorted form as well like below

```
audi,523487,456879
benz,876456,965471
bmw,754235,543298
```

Please help me in getting both outputs

Comment: Your dictionary does not have the data you want for output in your example. Can you update your example that shows data for benz, audi, bmw etc.? You want that sorted by vehicle's string (a-z)?

Comment: Hi, now I updated. Could you help me

Comment: You got some good answers @user13723838. I'd recommend that you put closure to your question by marking one of them as accepted. You can do so by clicking on a tick mark beside the answer of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
car_dict= {
'benz': {'usa':876456, 'uk':965471},
'audi' : {'usa':523487, 'uk':456879},
'bmw': {'usa':754235, 'uk':543298}
}

cars = []
for car in car_dict:
    cars.append('{},{},{}'.format(
        car,
        car_dict[car]['usa'],
        car_dict[car]['uk']
    ))
cars = sorted(cars)

for car in cars:
    print(cars)
```

**Result**

```
audi,523487,456879
benz,876456,965471
bmw,754235,543298
```

**Explanation**

Loop through each car and store the model, USA number and UK number in a list. Sort the list alphabetically. List it.

Answer (score 1):

To print the data

```
# Use List comprehension to sorted list of values from car, USA, UK fields
data = [[car] + list(regions.values()) for car, regions in sorted(car_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])]
for row in data:
  print(*row, sep = ',')
```

**Output**

```
audi,523487,456879
benz,876456,965471
bmw,754235,543298
```

**Explanation**

Sort items by car

```
for car, regions in sorted(car_dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Each inner list in list comprehension to be row of car, USA, UK values

```
[car] + list(regions.values())
```

Print each row comma delimited

```
for row in data:
    print(*row, sep = ',')
```

Comment: I like the use of list comprehension here. If you wanted more explicit control over the region ordering (or wanted a different ordering, you could replace the `[car] + list(regions.values())` with `[car, regions['usa'], regions['uk']]`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to print the outputs or just organize the data in a better format for analysis.

If latter, I would use pandas and do the following

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(car_dict).transpose().sort_index()
```

To view the output on terminal they way you requested,

```
for index, row in pd.DataFrame(car_dict).transpose().sort_index().iterrows():
    print('{},{},{}'.format(index, row['usa'], row['uk']))
```

will print this out:

```
audi,523487,456879
benz,876456,965471
bmw,754235,543298
```

Comment: I am looking for print the data

Answer (score 0):

Find below the solution,

```py
car_dict = {
            'benz': {'usa':876456, 'uk':965471},
            'audi' : {'usa':523487, 'uk':456879},
            'bmw': {'usa':754235, 'uk':543298}
           }

keys = list(car_dict.keys())
keys.sort()

for i in keys:
    print ( i, car_dict[i] ['usa'], car_dict[i] ['uk'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the list comprehension answer given by @DarrylG however you do not really need the lambda expression in this case.

`sorted()` will just do the sort by key by default, so you can just use :

```
data = [[car] + list(regions.values()) for car, regions in sorted(car_dict.items())]
```

I would also make another slight change. If you wanted more explicit control over the region ordering (or wanted a different ordering, you could replace the `[car] + list(regions.values())` with `[car, regions['usa'], regions['uk']]` like this:

```
data = [[car, regions['usa'], regions['uk']] for car, regions in sorted(car_dict.items())]
```

Of course, that means that if you added more regions you would have to change this, but I prefer setting the order explicitly.